# adding handle to a gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am struggling with adding a handle to a pics gallery. Here is the code that loads pics:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Click</button>

<div id="one"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){$("button").click(function(){$.post("/tests/pics.php",function(data){data=JSON.parse(data);
for (var i=2;i<data.length; i++){img=new Image(150,150);
    img.src="/tests/pics/"+data[i];
    $("div#one").append(img);} })
    }); }) 

</script>

</html>
```

with the pictures in tests.pics directory and php reading it:

```
<?php

$dir='C:/xampp1/htdocs/tests/pics';
$a=[]; $i=0;
if ($dh=opendir($dir)){while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false)
    {$a[$i]=$file; $i=$i+1;}
    closedir($dh);
}
echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

I would like to put event handle on, e.g., Alert when I click on any img. I understand the issue is with proper handling of img.onload.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the images and add a handler to that class:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){$("button").click(function(){$.post("/tests/pics.php",function(data){data=JSON.parse(data);
for (var i=2;i<data.length; i++){img=new Image(150,150);
    img.src="/tests/pics/"+data[i];
    img.class = "clickable-image";
    $("div#one").append(img);} })
    }); 
    $("div#one").on("click", ".clickable-image", function() {
        //alert your message here
    });
}); 

</script>
```